# Insert multiple rows, but for each row check if it does not already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am looking to insert multiple rows if they don't `EXIST` in the target table. But I'm not sure how do this with the following code:

```
INSERT INTO sales.promotions(
    promotion_name,
    discount,
    start_date,
    expired_date
)
VALUES
('2019 Summer Promotion', 0.15, '20190601', '20190901'),
('2019 Fall Promotion',   0.20, '20191001', '20191101'),
('2019 Winter Promotion', 0.25, '20191201', '20200101');
```

Because the `WHERE NOT EXIST` clause would apply to ALL rows whereas I need to do it row by row:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sales.promotions
    WHERE promotion_name = 'Winter Promotion');
```

Sorry if this is painfully obvious, not too good at SQL and I'm not really sure how to word this question for proper research.

Comment: Use a correlated sub query? You're not exactly clear here; are say you want to use a `NOT EXISTS` but the value you are checking for isn't one of the ones you are `INSERT`ing, so which row should it be stopping?

Comment: I'm saying I want to check the promotion name within each set of brackets to check if it's already in the database. If it is, none of the values within said brackets should be inserted. As I'm wanting to check multiple at once, that means I need to do different `NOT EXISTS` per bracketed query. Right?

Comment: Then use a correlated subquery, like I mentioned. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM... WHERE NOT EXISTS ({Correlated Subquery});`.

Comment: this should be done by placing a constraint on the [promotion_name] column, not by attempting to use a where clause in the insert statement see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with `exists`:

```
INSERT INTO sales.promotions(promotion_name, discount, start_date, expired_date)
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
    ('2019 Summer Promotion', 0.15, '20190601', '20190901'),
    ('2019 Fall Promotion',   0.20, '20191001', '20191101'),
    ('2019 Winter Promotion', 0.25, '20191201', '20200101')
) AS values_tobe_inserted(promotion_name, discount, start_date, expired_date)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sales.promotions
    WHERE sales.promotions.promotion_name = values_tobe_inserted.promotion_name
)
```

Comment: You, sir, are a legend.